# Cloud9 paid plan - More than one external port?

Tags: cloud9-ide

Does cloud9 give access to more than one external port with their paid plan? I know that free plan only has one but i am wondering about the paid one.

Comment: Multiple external ports are now available :) See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Workspaces now have 3 external ports, released a few days ago but not yet documented.

They have 8080 (the default), 8081 and 8082. To access them simply append the port number to your preview url (eg. http://projectname-username.c9.io:8081) and it will connect to whatever is running on port 8081.

These ports have some small issues with https which we'll improve over the next few days but http works fine.

Source: I work for Cloud9

Comment: I work for Cloud9. I don't think there is a docs page at the moment. Will create a doc page about it.